# For loop in Typescript to get data from JSON Array

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I am creating an application in Angular 8. The API I am using contains a JSON Array, as shown (partial):

```
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "summary":{
         "total":606,
         "confirmedCasesIndian":563,
         "confirmedCasesForeign":43,
         "discharged":43,
         "deaths":10,
         "confirmedButLocationUnidentified":0
      },
      "regional":[
         {
            "loc":"Andhra Pradesh",
            "confirmedCasesIndian":9,
            "confirmedCasesForeign":0,
            "discharged":1,
            "deaths":0
         },
         {
            "loc":"Bihar",
            "confirmedCasesIndian":4,
            "confirmedCasesForeign":0,
            "discharged":0,
            "deaths":1
         },
         {
            "loc":"Chhattisgarh",
            "confirmedCasesIndian":1,
            "confirmedCasesForeign":0,
            "discharged":0,
            "deaths":0
         },
         {
            "loc":"Delhi",
            "confirmedCasesIndian":30,
            "confirmedCasesForeign":1,
            "discharged":6,
            "deaths":1
         }
      ]
   },
   "lastRefreshed":"2020-03-26T04:18:02.528Z",
   "lastOriginUpdate":"2020-03-25T13:15:00.000Z"
}
```

**component.ts**

```
  constructor(private _IndiaApiService: IndiaApiService) { }

  info:IndiaClass[]
  regional:[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this._IndiaApiService.getIndiaData()
    .subscribe
    (
      data=>
      {
        this.info = data;
      }
    )
  }

 }
```

**component.html**

```
<table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Recovered cases</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>{{ info.data.regional[0].loc }}</td>
                <td>{{ info.data.regional[0].discharged }}</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

The output of the above is as expected, I'm getting a table with data from the first element of the array.
Now I need to loop this through regional[0] to regional[24]. (There are 25 elements in the array dataset)

How do I do it using *ngFor? Is there any other way to apply the loop? 
Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: @Bloopy just take a look and this chapter: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data. And use *ngFor directive on your tr (row of table) element

Comment: Would you please share the full JSON object hierarchy you're receiving? you may look for a nested-loop solution however your object doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what exactly you're looking for. But you could try the following

```html
<tr *ngFor="let region of info.data.regional">
  <td>{{ region.loc }}</td>
  <td>{{ region.discharged }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This worked. I am new to Angular so I wasn't able to figure out the logic for *ngFor. Thanks!

Comment: In that case it'd serve you better to go through this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces all basic concepts of Angular.